# Calling tibco webservcie from java client

Tags: java, web-services, client, tibco

I have been given WSDL and XSD files for Tibco Web service. Along with that I have Tibco queue details.
I need to hit the Tibco sync queue and get the response from the queue.
My question is hot to create the java stub(client) with appropriate endpoint address.
When I create the stub using CXF, it says "nvalid endpoint address" while I running the stub client.

There is another option to send request to queue using spring's WebServiceTemplate. But to construct the input XML message.

Does any one call the Tibco webservice from Java? Which is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful if you post the actual WSDL you have problems with.
I assume the WSDL was generated with TIBCO Businessworks. TIBCO supports exposing WSDL's with JMS Transport bindings a long while in a proprietary way before a SOAP over JMS standard from W3C was defined.
CXF implemented the W3C standard so it won't understand the binding and you ll have to do some hand wiring for the transport of your client like described e.g. here:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-the-jmsconfigfeature.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the problem is actually in the generated client, and not the WSDL or the given endpoint is worng, First try to test the wsdl with SOAP UI or any similar tool.

if it works then you can check what is wrong with the generated client.